# Vuetify v-data-table not displaying :headers and :items

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to build a Vue project using typescript. My v-data-table component inside Schedule.vue is not displaying. Instead all I see is the following:

[image]

I've tried googling everything I can but with no luck. I'm now at a point where I just re-create my project from scratch.

Here is my Schedule.vue file:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          <v-data-table :headers="daoHeaders" :items="daoItems" :items-per-page="5" class="elevation-1">
            <v-toolbar-title>{{ dsTitle }}</v-toolbar-title>
          </v-data-table>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          This is below the table
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      daoHeaders: [
        { title: 'Sport', key: 'sportName', align: 'start', sortable: true },
        { title: 'League', key: 'leagueName' },
        { title: 'Grade Level', key: 'gradeLevel' }
      ],
      daoItems: [
        { sportName: 'Basketball', leagueName: 'Spring Basketball League', gradeLevel: '6-12' }
      ],
      dsTitle: 'This is my Title'
    }
  },
  methods: {
  }
});
</script>
```

Here is my index.ts file:

```html
/**
 * plugins/index.ts
 *
 * Automatically included in `./src/main.ts`
 */

// Plugins
import { loadFonts } from './webfontloader'
import vuetify from './vuetify'
import router from '../router'

// Types
import type { App } from 'vue'

export function registerPlugins (app: App) {
  loadFonts()
  app
    .use(vuetify)
    .use(router)
}
```

```html
/**
 * main.ts
 *
 * Bootstraps Vuetify and other plugins then mounts the App`
 */

// Components
import App from './App.vue'

// Composables
import { createApp } from 'vue'

// Plugins
import { registerPlugins } from '@/plugins'

const app = createApp(App)

registerPlugins(app)

app.mount('#app')
```

Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
       "src/*"
      ]
     }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue", "src/main.ts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong naming in your v-data-table headers.

To show the data. Change your **daoHeaders** from *title* and *key* to *text* and *value*.

*FROM*

```
daoHeaders: [
        { title: 'Sport', key: 'sportName', align: 'start', sortable: true },
        { title: 'League', key: 'leagueName' },
        { title: 'Grade Level', key: 'gradeLevel' }
      ],
```

*TO*

```
daoHeaders: [
          { text: 'Sport', value: 'sportName', align: 'start', sortable: true },
          { text: 'League', value: 'leagueName' },
          { text: 'Grade Level', value: 'gradeLevel' }
        ],
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This verbage is used for vue2, For vue3 v-data-table now uses 'title' and 'key'

Comment: For some reason I'm unable to answer my own question but following the steps here fixed my issue:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/

Comment: Ok. I'm glad you find a way to fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

As [@MJenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6500908/m-jenkins) mentioned in a comment:
For now v-data-table on Vuetify 3 is a component from Labs, therefore it is necessary to import it locally from Labs with:

```
  import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/VDataTable'
```

or globally with:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/VDataTable'

export default createVuetify({
  components: {
    VDataTable,
  },
})
```

as per the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/#usage).

When it is not imported the v-data-table will be loaded similarly to:

```
<v-data-table data-v-hash="" modelvalue="" items-per-page="10" 
headers="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" 
items="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" 
item-key="key" search="" loading="false" hide-default-footer="" 
show-select="" fixed-header=""></v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change your header, in my case v-data-table working but i don't show header, solutions is change this:

```
headers: [
{ text: 'Name user', value: 'name_user' },
 ]
```

to

```
headers: [
{ title: 'Name user', key: 'name_user' },
 ]
```